# activerecord - getting the most popular category

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model Category and class method tickets_num which return the number of tickets that belongs to this category:
Category.first.tickets_num # => 2

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tickets

  def tickets_num
    self.tickets.count
  end
end
```

I would like to do controller method "popular" which will return me 3 categories with the highest number of tickets_num , how can I do it in the most elegant way?

```
def popular
  @categories = Category.order(tickets_num).all.limit(3)
end
```

my method doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following active record query should get you what you need.  Not sure if there is a cleaner way to do that.

```
Category.select("categories.*, COUNT(tickets.id) AS t_count").joins(:tickets).group("categories.id").order("t_count DESC").limit(3)
```